# How to Connect to a Wireless Network That Uses a Security Pin on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking

I can connect to the wireless network at home using a PC. It uses WPA/WPA2 and the first thing I need to input when I try to connect is a security pin, once I do that and I get a response, I can type the WEP key as well and connect.

When I try to connect using a Mac, the pin option nevers shows up.

I tried to configure going though:
System Preferences > Network > AirPort > Advanced
From the there selected the network and clicked the pencil icon
and for the Security option I've picked WPA2 Personal, but there is no prompt for the initial security key. When I type the wep key directly I get an IP that is not working 169.etc.etc.etc. instead of 192.168.etc.etc.

What option do I need to choose to connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the equivalent of the 'PIN' on windows is DHCP Client ID in TCP/IP settings (Network Advanced settings)